# How to click the button to crawl the reviews using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to crawl the reviews on this website: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Matras-140x200-7-zones-koudschuim-premium-plus-tijk-15-cm-medium/9200000118425897/.

However, I have to click a button ( Toon meer) to show all the reviews.

```
<div class="load-more load-more--divider load-more--reviews js-review-load-more-container">
  <a data-href="/nl/rnwy/productPage/reviews?productId=9200000118425896&amp;offset=5&amp;limit=10&amp;loadMore=true" class="review-load-more__button js-review-load-more-button" data-test="review-load-more"><div class="css-loader css-loader--reviews"></div>
      Toon meer</a>
</div>
```

I use the below code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
data = []
link = "https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Matras-140x200-7-zones-koudschuim-premium-plus-tijk-15-cm-medium/9200000118425897/"
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
op.add_argument('--incognito')
op.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Desktop/work/real/chromedriver.exe',options=op)
driver.get(link)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.review-load-more__button js-review-load-more-button').click()
```

However, it throws an error:

```
No such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.review-load-more__button js-review-load-more-button"} .
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on <kbd>Toon meer</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Matras-140x200-7-zones-koudschuim-premium-plus-tijk-15-cm-medium/9200000118425896/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-test='consent-modal-confirm-btn']>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.review-load-more__button.js-review-load-more-button"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Matras-140x200-7-zones-koudschuim-premium-plus-tijk-15-cm-medium/9200000118425896/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-test='consent-modal-confirm-btn']/span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='review-load-more__button js-review-load-more-button' and contains(., 'Toon meer')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive solution. I tried to run by using css_selector. However, sometimes it can click the button, sometimes it does not. I dont know why. Should I extend the waiting time ?

Comment: @mht Yes, the is a dependency on the network connectivity. I was able to reduce the waiting time to `20` secs. You may need to adjust.

Comment: How can I determine the waiting time ? How can I get the network connectivity ( I guess it is a number ?) ?

Comment: @mht Apologies, instead of _network connectivity_ we should consider it as the time required for the desired element to render within the HTML and this specific value should be part of your _Test Plan_ / _testcase_.

Answer (score 2):

Css selectors cannot select an element by containing text.

Try using xpath. The last line of your script should look something like:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Toon meer')]")).click()
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it threw an error : element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (202, 1865). What does it mean ?

Comment: that means another element (invisible) is blocking the click. Add a wait condition as in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the page a popup comes with an accept button click it and then proceed with clicking your element.

```
driver.get('https://www.bol.com/nl/p/Matras-140x200-7-zones-koudschuim-premium-plus-tijk-15-cm-medium/9200000118425896/')
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='js-confirm-button']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-test='review-load-more']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```